# Wordpress & section video background sizing issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

after browsing many forums and suggestions on similar issues I gave up. I'm preparing a website http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/graffitx-2/ and have a section where there's a video in the background (just second screen on scroll). I can't get it to resize according to the screen resolution and the video is just cropped from the right by 1/3. I think I tried almost every solution I could find - to no avail (obviously not every).
Any ideas would be very welcome. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

OK so from the question title you are using Wordpress with the theme 'jupiter-child'. The theme has customized the background video to be responsive.

But if you want to adjust the values you would have to go into the file that contains 'element.style' variable and adjust to your desire.

Typically that background video is preset with values for the theme.

[Here is what your looking for (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P1Rl.png)

[If you need to find it in the wordpress theme (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrwAS.png)

Comment: That element.style place you are refering to was the first place too look for adjustments. I was not able to adjust the width of the wideo to make it 100% of viewport either in the WP section settings, nor in the element.style css section. Any advice on specific css modifications to make it responsive-adjust?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I made it work using this

```
.video-section .mk-section-video {
min-height: 100%!important;
height: 100%!important;
}
.video-section .mk-section-video video {
max-width: 100%!important;
}
```